# pandas: split dataframe into multiple csvs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a large file, imported into a single dataframe in Pandas.
I'm using pandas to split up a file into many segments, by the number of rows in the dataframe.

eg:  10 rows:
file 1 gets [0:4]
file 2 gets [5:9]

Is there a way to do this without having to create more dataframes?

Comment: split by what kind of rule ?

Comment: thanks for the catch.  I've updated the question with that detail

Comment: `df.iloc[0:4,:].to_csv(path)` and just iterate over that...

Comment: `df.iloc[:4,:]` and  `df.iloc[5:,:]`

Comment: What's the reason why this has to be done in pandas?  From the current description (large file, being split by rows) you could do it from the command line using 'split'.

Comment: 0:4, and 5:9 are toy examples.  In reality, I'm looking at 0:200e6 - 1, 200e6:400e6 -1

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of doing this.  I believe you are looking for the former.  Basically, we open a series of csv writers, then we write to the correct csv writer by using some basic math with the index, then we close all files.

## A single DataFrame evenly divided into N number of CSV files

```
import pandas as pd
import csv, math

df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) # uncreative input values for 10 columns
NUMBER_OF_SPLITS = 2
fileOpens = [open(f"out{i}.csv","w") for i in range(NUMBER_OF_SPLITS)]
fileWriters = [csv.writer(v, lineterminator='\n') for v in fileOpens]
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    fileWriters[math.floor((i/df.shape[0])*NUMBER_OF_SPLITS)].writerow(row.tolist())
for file in fileOpens:
    file.close()
```

## More than one DataFrame evenly divided into N number of CSV files

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) # uncreative input values for 10 columns
NUMBER_OF_SPLITS = 2
for i, new_df in enumerate(np.array_split(df,NUMBER_OF_SPLITS)):
    with open(f"out{i}.csv","w") as fo:
            fo.write(new_df.to_csv())
```

Comment: This solution forces the creation of a new df.

Comment: @billyc59 Updated it.

Comment: Why do you use the file write method in combination with `df.to_csv()`. The `.to_csv()` method is already writing data to a file. In your case, I will get empty rows in the new CSVs.

Answer (score 4):

`assign` a new column g here, you just need to specific how many item you want in each groupby, here I am using 3 .

```
df.assign(g=df.index//3)
Out[324]: 
    0  g
0   1  0
1   2  0
2   3  0
3   4  1
4   5  1
5   6  1
6   7  2
7   8  2
8   9  2
9  10  3
```

and you can call the `df[df.g==1]` to get what you need

Comment: do we really need that new column? `df[np.arange(len(df))//3==1]`

Answer (score 1):

use numpy.array_split to split your dataframe dfX and save it in N csv files of equal size: dfX_1.csv to dfX_N.csv

```
N = 10
for i, df in enumerate(np.array_split(dfX, N)):
    df.to_csv(f"dfX_{i + 1}.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

iterating over iloc's arguments will do the trick.